# How to improve SPARQL Update performance in Blazegraph?

Tags: performance, sparql, triplestore, blazegraph

I'm trying to execute a large SPARQL Update request, basically with one `INSERT DATA` command, and a set of `DELETE ... WHERE` commands. The request performs an insertion of some triples and removes the old values of functional properties of individuals, affected by the `INSERT` command, in order to keep the data consistent; 300-400 operations per request on average. To perform the request I use Apache Jena's `UpdateProcessor` with SPARQL Update endpoint of Blazegraph (`http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/update`):

```
UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(request, updateUrl, client);
processor.execute()
```

Execution time of such request is about 5-7 seconds on average on my laptop, but I also noticed that CPU and disk utilization by Blazegraph itself are low although the response time is long. I guess, if there is a bottleneck, something should reach the ceiling (100% of CPU, or high dist I/O). But they are still low... Bulk load is not applicable here, because I need not only add the new triples, but also modify the dataset according to these new triples.

How could it be improved? Maybe I missed something in the Blazegraph configuration...

Here is my `RWStore.properties`:

```
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.truthMaintenance=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.textIndex=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.axiomsClass=com.bigdata.rdf.axioms.NoAxioms

com.bigdata.rdf.sail.isolatableIndices=false
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.bufferCapacity=100000

com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=./journal/blazegraph.jnl
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.bufferMode=DiskRW

com.bigdata.btree.writeRetentionQueue.capacity=4000
com.bigdata.btree.BTree.branchingFactor=512

com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.commit=Incremental
```

Blazegraph version 2.1.1. Startup options:

```
java -server -Xmx8g -XX:+UseG1GC -Dbigdata.propertyFile=RWStore.properties -jar blazegraph.jar
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
```